# is it possible to read/write from/to a txt file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, file

is it possible to read/write from/to a txt file using JavaScript, and this file be uploaded to the server and anyone can access it, literally saying, using this txt file as a database?

NOTE: I don't mean the browser's side, I mean to the same place the website is uploaded "the server's side"

Comment: Not just with js code, you would need some server implementation also.

Comment: It would be possible to download the file into browser, edit the file in JavaScript and upload to server as text. Server would need to be set-up to accept text and create the file. There must be a better way though. What's wrong with a database?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use [http communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722765/saving-text-file-on-server-using-javascript) with your server handling storage

heres [how it can be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587973/javascript-upload-file)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/image" method="post">
    <input id="image-file" type="file" />
</form
```