# Writing Data into CSV File located at particular path on Client Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, csv

The application which am working is an static application which is built on Angular JS technology. I want to write data into CSV File located at particular path so that another API can read data from that path(CSV File). I had searched a lot in internet but i could not find correct solution. Could you please help me regarding this. Technology can be any client side like Angular JS,Jquery,Java Script.

Comment: you can only save to the user's downloads folder under normal browser operating conditions.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that without an server like node, apache (php), ... to save the data.

-> [Saving a text file on server using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722765/saving-text-file-on-server-using-javascript)

Comment: Is there a any way to do in opposite. I.e reading data from CSV file located at particular location.? using the same technologies

Comment: Yes but you need the location of the file, if you have dynamic files, you can put a json with the paths/names into the folder (generated by the server or something).